# Convert carriage return into a line break - regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My example string:

```
var text = "aaaaaaa↵bbbbbb↵cccccc"
```

expected outcome after regex:

```
"aaaaaaa\nbbbbbb\ncccccc"
```

which translates to (html):

```
aaaaaaa

bbbbbb

cccccc
```

Or instead of translating, the regex identifies `↵` as a line break too, I've tried this regex to target all of the arrows and the line breaks

```
↵[^\n]*\n[^\n]*
```

Link to my sample: https://regexr.com/577ge

Comment: Why not just `text.replace(/↵/g, "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

You could split it up first and then joint it with `\n` or `<br />`

```js
var text = "aaaaaaa↵bbbbbb↵cccccc"

let result = text.split("↵").join("\n");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log(text.replace(/↵/g, "\n"));` to replace the with `\n`
and if you want to use the same for HTML then use

`console.log(text.replace(/↵/g, "<br>"));`

```js
var text = "aaaaaaa↵bbbbbb↵cccccc";
console.log(text.replace(/↵/g, "\n"));
console.log(text.replace(/↵/g, "<br>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
str.replace(/↵/g, "\\n")
```